ubuntu server blocking IOS device http requests
I have a IONIC application and it makes http requests to a linux ubuntu machine running docker containers.The requests work fine on a Android devices but fail on a IOS devices.
StatusCode = 0, Status=unknown. The app uses TLS 1.3, and the server's SSL certificate is valid.We thought it might be the containers but we moved the containers to another linux server and it works fine.
Any ideas?

What is the version of Ubuntu being used?
